# how to convert <br> to newline in angular html

Tags: java, html, angular5

I am passing an email body from java to angular which has some line breaks. But, in angular the line breaks come as `<br>` instead of newline.

**Java code**

```
sbEmailBody.append("Dear All,<br/><br/>");
sbEmailBody.append("Please be advised that following has been Approved.<br/><br/>");
template.setEmailBody(sbEmailBody.toString());
```

**Angular component.html**

```
<textarea class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="email.emailBody" 
name="email.emailBody" rows="10" [disabled]="true"></textarea>
```

Comment: try replacing `<br/>` with `\n` in your java code?

Comment: oh it worked! Thanks a lot..

Comment: No worries, moved it to answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<br/>` with `\n` in your java code, otherwise it's a part of text.